# Anti-Scraping bypass?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

Helllo,

I'm working on a scraper for this page : https://www.dirk.nl/
I'm trying to get in scrapy shell the 'row-wrapper' div class.
If I enter `response.css('row-wrapper')`, it gives me some random results, I think an anti scraping system is involved. I need the hrefs from this class.

Any opinions on how can I move forward ?

Comment: We would need a little bit more data. What about the response you recieve?

Answer (score 1):

We would need a little bit more data, like the response you receive and any code if it's already set up.

But from the looks of it, it can be multiple things ( from 429 Response blocking the request because of the rate limit to sites internal API XHR causing data to not be rendered on page load etc. ).

Before fetching any website for scraping reasons, try `curl`, `postman` or `insomnia` software to see what type of the response are you going to receive. Some special servers and website architectures require certain cookies and headers while some don't. You simply have to do this research so you can make your scraping workflow efficient.

I ran `curl https://www.dirk.nl/` and it returned data that's generated by `Nuxt` framework. In this case that data is unusable since `Nuxt` uses it's own functionality to parse data.

Instead, the best solution would be not to get the HTML based data but API content data.

Something like this:

```
curl 'https://content-api.dirk.nl/misc/specific/culios.aspx?action=GetRecipe' \
  -H 'accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
  --data-raw '{"id":"11962"}' \
  --compressed
```

Will return:

```
{"id":11962,"slug":"Muhammara kerstkrans","title":"Muhammara kerstkrans","subtitle":"", ...Rest of the data
```

I don't understand this language but from my basic understanding this would be an API route for recipes.

Comment: I will try to pursue the Nuxt script. When I run the response.css mentioned earlier I get, other hrefs than the one I see in the inspector : ' '/aanbiedingen',
 '/inspiratie/sinterklaas',
 'https://www.dirk.nl/aanbiedingen/ambachtelijke-chocoladeletter/74553',
 'https://www.dirk.nl/aanbiedingen/pick-mix-tapas/74565',
 '/aanbiedingen',
 '/boodschappen/zuivel-kaas/kaas-gesneden/milner-komijn-30-plakken/34279',
 '/boodschappen/zuivel-kaas/kaas-gesneden/milner-komijn-30-plakken/34279',
 '/boodschappen/zuivel-kaas/kaas-gesneden/milner-komijn-30-plakken/34279',' etc...

Comment: I'm trying to parse the script, but I'm stuck :scripts = response.css('script').getall()
nuxt_script_list = [script for script in scripts if 'window.__NUXT__' in script]      
nuxt_script = nuxt_script_list[0].replace('<script>window.__NUXT__=', '').replace('</script>', '')
 json_data = js2py.eval_js(nuxt_script)                             . Now I cannot access nothing in that json . Example from the json : {'ID': '7426', 'authLevel': '1', ' ... if I go json_data['ID'] it displays nothing ...